# How do Android components look like on different themes?

Tags: android, button, dialog, themes, android-theme

I want to know how all the Android components such as dialogs, buttons,.. will look like on different themes.

Somebody got a blog or an article for this? Thank you.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio, you can open xml file on preview mode and switch theme from dropdown box.

Comment: @mr.icetea This should be the answer.

Comment: @mr.icetea How can I not think of that? I'm using Xamarin Studio and it has preview mode too :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of different Android themes:
http://android.appstorm.net/how-to/customization/dress-up-your-android-with-gorgeous-themes/

As a developper, I'll say that the appearance depends on what you're using for example for a button you may re-program your own button to use in your custom theme by adding an image in the button's background, change the button's shape or color .. and of course you can also change the look at each state (pressed, focused,etc.).